# ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID for Rails app on was elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a webapp deployed to aws elastic beanstalk with a custom domain. In the DNS settings, I've set up to a records for `www.myssite.com` and `mysite.com` to the value of my public elastic beanstalk url. I have also configured an SSL certificate through Amazon's ACM for `*.mysite.com` and `mysite.com`. For some reason, mainly on chrome, some images I have stored with active storage give me an error `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

If I visit the url I get this.

> This server could not prove that it is myapp.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com; its security certificate is from mystic.com This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

I'm unsure on what to do, and am very confused as to why it happens to some images and not others. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have setup SSL for `www.myssite.com` then every link on your website to images, css or js, should be going through your domain which has proper SSL certificate.

`myapp.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com` is AWS managed domain and it does not your SSL certificate associated with it. Thus leading to the issues you are observing.

Comment: Hey, I do understand that, but the issue lies if I turn off the force_ssl, and the requests are done through http, then I get an issue with using http and https that prevents images from showing.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your application is serving some images using the elasticbeanstalk.com domain name and not the custom domain that you set up. It seems like you have already been able to identify some of those URLs. If you used the application using the elasticbeanstalk.com domain name when you were setting up your application, that is probably how the URLs were stored there in the first place.

The URLs are most likely coming from your database. You will have to audit your database records and update the URLs stored there. You may also be able to replace the domain name in the URLs when they are served to the client, but this depends on how much control you have of the application code. If possible, try serving the URLs with relative paths instead of absolute URLs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! The images are all stored on amazon S3, but it looks like the requests are all made through the myapp.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com domain. Any idea how I could change that?

Comment: That would depend a lot on the application itself. Did you write the application or are you using an open source application like Wordpress?

Comment: Its an open source app, spree commerce. I can amend the code with decoraters

Comment: I would recommend that you try to inspect the database (for example, using MySQL Workbench or equivalent tools) to see if there are URLs in it that are referencing the elasticbeanstalk.com domain name. If that's the case, either manually (or write a script) to replace the domain name.

Comment: yeah, I did that early on to check but it seems to just store the file path without the original url :/